# How to remove all ul and li, but still keep current-menu-item in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-nav-walker

I am trying to output through wp_nav this structure through WordPress, but still keep a class for the current menu item, so the tab changes on the current page. (is-active would replace the current-menu-item). This is based on https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section

```
<!-- Simple header with scrollable tabs. -->
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
  <header class="mdl-layout__header">
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <!-- Title -->
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
    </div>
    <!-- Tabs -->
    <div class="mdl-layout__tab-bar mdl-js-ripple-effect">
      <a href="#scroll-tab-1" class="mdl-layout__tab is-active">Tab 1</a>
      <a href="#scroll-tab-2" class="mdl-layout__tab">Tab 2</a>
      <a href="#scroll-tab-3" class="mdl-layout__tab">Tab 3</a>
      <a href="#scroll-tab-4" class="mdl-layout__tab">Tab 4</a>
      <a href="#scroll-tab-5" class="mdl-layout__tab">Tab 5</a>
      <a href="#scroll-tab-6" class="mdl-layout__tab">Tab 6</a>
    </div>
  </header>
 </div>
```

However, I don't know how to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: you need to list menu in above format , right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. So my primary menu would be in the links.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the original data upon which you wish to perform such action to get the required output.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. I am trying to get the data from wp_nav and then output that data in that html format

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function remove_wp_nav_menu_ul_litags($menu){
  return $menu = strip_tags($menu, "<a>");
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu', 'remove_wp_nav_menu_ul_litags' );
```

You can preserve or keep other tags as well by passing as the second parameter of the **strip_tags()** function.

Answer (score 0):

This task is a bit more difficult than it seems. `wp_nav_menu()` uses a special [Walker class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker) which builds dynamic output. There is a bunch of hardcoded and filtered classnames and tons of flags/states. And we have three major methods to deal with all this.

- The simplest way is to keep the default markup and adopt/rewrite all related CSS/JS instead. It's much easier in 90% cases for beginners.
- Another way is using [nav-menu hooks and filters](https://developer.wordpress.org/?s=nav_menu&post_type%5B%5D=wp-parser-hook) to add/redefine existing classes. It's ok if you just need some tuning. Typically you would use: '[nav_menu_css_class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_css_class/)', '[nav_menu_submenu_css_class](http://nav_menu_submenu_css_class)', '[nav_menu_link_attributes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_link_attributes/)'. Some things can be also replaced by regular expressions after the output html is ready (using '[wp_nav_menu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu/)' filter). This method may appear slow sometimes, because you often have to loop through everything (items, classes, attributes) and perform excessive conditional checks. But it seems your task fits this method completely.
- The most flexible way is to extend Walker class by your own walker functions which will provide any output you need in your own way. However, you'll need to [understand the Walker Class](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-the-walker-class--wp-25401) (tutorial). This method might seem complicated when you face it for the first time. But it gives you full control.